# SQL FOR DATA BETWEEN JOIN DATE and LEAVING DATE OF EMPLOYEE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one Employee who has joining two time.Please review below table.

```
EmpID    EmpName    DateOFJoin    DateOfLeaving    Status
1         XYZ       2015-10-01    2017-09-26       De-Active
2         ABC       2018-01-01                     Active                      
3         XYZ       2018-10-15                     Active
```

I want output like 
For Instance,
I have FromDate and ToDate like '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-31'

```
EmpID    EmpName    DateOFJoin    DateOfLeaving    Status
2         ABC       2018-01-01                     Active 
3         XYZ       2018-10-15                     Active
```

IF I have FromDate and ToDate like '2017-08-01' and '2017-09-30'

```
EmpID    EmpName    DateOFJoin    DateOfLeaving    Status
1         XYZ       2015-10-01    2017-09-26       De-Active
```

IF I have FromDate and ToDate like '2018-01-01' and '2018-03-31'

```
EmpID    EmpName    DateOFJoin    DateOfLeaving    Status
2         ABC       2018-01-01                     Active
```

Please Help to prepare SQL For it.

Comment: what is your ouput if fromDate and Todate would be '2018-02-01' and '2018-03-01'

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Answer (score 2):

Use `coalesce()` function

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=29e0512df48205c4efdd922c2cf7884f)**

```
select EmpID,EmpName,DateOFJoin,DateOfLeaving,Status
from tablename
where DateOFJoin<=param1 and coalesce(DateOfLeaving,param2)>=param2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this in your process:

```
   GO
   select * into #temptable from 
   (select EmpID,EmpName,DateOFJoin,DateOfLeaving,Status from table 
   where (DateOFJoin between @startdate and @enddate) or ( DateOfLeaving between @startdate and @enddate) ) as d

   if exists (select Empid from #temptable)
   Begin
   select EmpID,EmpName,DateOFJoin,DateOfLeaving,Status from #temptable
   End
   Else
   Begin
   select EmpID,EmpName,DateOFJoin,DateOfLeaving,Status from table where DateOfLeaving is null
   End
   drop table #temptable
   GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE DateOFJoin <= ToDate AND COALESCE(DateOfLeaving, FromDate) >= FromDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `WHERE` with `ISNULL()`:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM yourTable t
WHERE T.DateOfJoin <=@FromDate AND ISNULL(T.DateOfLeaving, @ToDate)>=@ToDate
```

Let me show an example:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE 
(
EmpID int, 
EmpName varchar(50),    
DateOfJoin datetime,
DateOfLeaving DATETIME,
StatusName VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    EmpID,
    EmpName,
    DateOfJoin,
    DateOfLeaving,
    StatusName
)
VALUES
 (1, 'XYZ',      '2015-10-01',    '2017-09-26', 'De-ACTIVE')
,(2, 'ABC',      '2018-01-01',    NULL, 'ACTIVE')                      
,(3, 'XYZ',      '2018-10-15',    NULL, 'ACTIVE')    


DECLARE   @FromDate  VARCHAR(50) = '2019-12-01'
        , @ToDate  VARCHAR(50) = '2019-12-31'
SELECT 
* 
FROM @table t
WHERE T.DateOfJoin <=@FromDate AND ISNULL(T.DateOfLeaving, @ToDate)>=@ToDate
```